# For Loop Timer Function in Python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, math, numpy, modulus

So I created a program that runs in command prompt and inside my program an array has to be iterated through a for loop:

```
counter=0
for i in range(0,rows):
    for j in range(0,cols):
        array[i,j]=3 #just an arbitrary number
    counter=Time_Function(i,rows,counter,0)
```

I need to time the array in cmd like this:

```
>>0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100
```

I got it to work for one array with rows=2018, cols=486, but when I input a different array with rows=2023, cols=486 it gives me this:

```
>>0....10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100
```

I really want to get rid of that pesky extra period between `0` and `10`! I know this probably occurs because the 2nd array has more rows, but I can't seem to fix it using the current knowledge I have of the modulus operator :( This is the `Time_Function` I created:

```
def Time_Function(i,rows,counter,start):
    if  i==start or i% round(rows/10) ==0:
        sys.stdout.write(str(counter))
        counter=counter+10
    if i% round((rows/10)/3) ==0:  #check update, I tried the condition i!=start
        sys.stdout.write('.')
    return counter
```

(Note: I know this might seem like a very minor issue but that extra period looks so gross so I need to get rid of it)

UPDATE: I tried the suggested code (put `i!=start` condition in the 2nd `if statement`) and it gave me this:

```
>> 0..10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100.

>> 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100
```

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
def Time_Function(i,rows,counter,start,var):

    if  i==start or i% round(rows/10) ==0 and counter <=100:
        sys.stdout.write(str(counter))
        counter=counter+10
        var=0
    if i% round((rows/10)/3) ==0 and counter <=100 and var<3:  
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        var=var+1
    return [counter,var] 

def Project(array,rows,cols):
    counter=var=0
    for i in range(0,rows):
        for j in range(0,cols):
            array=3 #just an arbitrary number
        [counter,var]=Time_Function(i,rows,counter,0,var)

array1=1
array2=2
Project(array1,2018,486)
print "\n"
Project(array2,2023,486)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your function lies within the second if statement. A modulo of 0 (your current start number) also generates a dot which you don't expect.

So checking if i isn't your start number or isn't zero should get your function correct.

Comment: It's part of the problem, but basically the amount of dots between the counts relies on the amount of rows. Also the rounding of the numbers has some effect as round is either up or down. Do you want have always 3 dots or just the same amount of dots between the counters?